# How to parse a baseball box score in R

Tags: string, r

I am working on a research project with baseball data from retrosheet.org.  I want to create variables for the score of each team in each inning (Vis1, Home1, Vis2, Home2, etc).  The problem is that the variable for the box score is coded strangely.  Each team has its own variable for the whole game and each inning gets one value.  Because leading zeros are cut off a value of "12(10)1X" would mean that a team did not score in the first 4 innings, scored once in the fifth, twice in the sixth, ten times in the seventh, once in the eighth, and they did not have to play the ninth because they had won by that point.

Any advice?  I'm at a loss.  The () confuse me the most.

Comment: Can you post a more direct link to a dataset in question?

Comment: I combined all of the regular season data on this page into one dataset: http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/index.html

Comment: Thanks.  So - something's going wrong in your importation of the data if the leading zeroes are being truncated.  I pulled 1995 into R using the `read.csv` function, and all of the box scores included the leading zeroes.  That *radically* simplifies your request!  Now the "(10)" bit is the most difficult, rather than trying to figure out which character represents which inning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm irish and live in wales and have no clue about baseball but, I think I remember hearing that there can only be a maximum of 9 innings???? (honestly... no clue!!!)

```
bbscore = function(x)
{
 scores = c()
 score = unlist(strsplit(x,split=""))
 i= 1
 while(i<length(score)+1)
 {
   if(score[i]=="(")
   {
     scores = c(scores,paste(score[i+1],score[i+2],sep=""))
     i = i+4
   }
   scores = c(scores,score[i])
   i = i+1
 }
 return(scores)
}
> x
[1] "12(10)1X"
> bbscore(x)
[1] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "2"  "10" "1"  "X" 

> scores.df = read.csv("GL1995.TXT",header=F)
> head(scores.df$V20)
[1] 200030300 000000000 000300020 000000010 100100010 001002300
1355 Levels: (11)00033102 00000000 000000000 0000000000 ... 710001001
> scores.df$V20 = as.character(scores.df$V20)
> V20.1995.scores = lapply(scores.df$V21, bbscore)
> V20.1995.scores = lapply(scores.df$V20, bbscore)
> V20.1995.scores[[1]]
[1] "2" "0" "0" "0" "3" "0" "3" "0" "0"
> V20.1995.scores[[2]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
> V20.1995.scores[[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0" "3" "0" "0" "0" "2" "0"
```

Of course you'll have to do some furhter manipulations to get them into numbers and deal with X's and also this will break if there are any other unexpected characters, in addition to being beholden to the assumption of 9 innings.

**EDIT:**
I removed the stipulation for 9 innings and show how to do this for the entire column (assuming that scores you spoke of are indeed the 20th variable in the csv file). Extra porcessing is required for different number of innings. `do.call(rbind,...)` won't work. find the longest game and append `"X"`'s to the end to make them all the same length? Maybe? I'm not sure but I think this question has been answered at least.

Comment: Also, an actual clever person might some how use regular expressions. Not me though! :(

Comment: Unfortunately, baseball games can go into extra innings if the score is tied at the end of 9.  Fortunately, if you check out the OP's data in comments on the question, it looks like the leading zeroes are actually intact.  Would you mind taking another pass on the actual data?  I think you're on the right track...

Comment: I just checked and 17 innings was the most any game had.
`> max(sapply(scores.df$V20, nchar))  
[1] 17`

Comment: @DavyKavanagh - actually, I recall there was a professional baseball game that went far longer than that, 33 innings to be exact. Right in my town in fact. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_professional_baseball_game

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in this talk at useR! 2012 that may provide more information specific to your baseball project.
You can find it [here.](http://www.slideshare.net/rtelmore/user-2012-talk)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but...

There is a new R package for fetching data from the [MLB server](http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/) including box score and much more. Might be worth a look!

- [openWar](https://github.com/beanumber/openWAR)